# Boost Asio, async UDP client - crash on shutdown

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I use UDP client-server for IPC in my application

It works fine, but when trying to shutdown the client side some race condition happen, which causes application crash or deadlock.

UDP client:

```
// IOServiceBase class contain boost::asio::io_service instance
// it is accessible by service() protected method
class AsyncUDPClient : public IOServiceBase
{
public:

    /// @brief Create a network client
    AsyncUDPClient(const std::string& host, const std::string port)
        : _host(host)
        , _port(port)
        , _reply()
        , _work(service())
        , _sock(service(), ba_ip::udp::endpoint(ba_ip::udp::v4(), 0)) {

        run();
    }

    /// @brief Start async packets processing
    void run(){
        std::thread t([&]{ service().run(); });
        t.detach();
    }

    /// @brief Async request to server
    void send(uint8_t* message, size_t length) {
        std::vector<uint8_t> packet(message, message + length);
        service().post(boost::bind(&AsyncUDPClient::do_send, this, packet));
    }

    /// @brief Cleanup io_service to dismiss already putted tasks
    ~AsyncUDPClient() {
        close();

        // trying to wait until service is stopped, but it does not help
        while (!service().stopped()){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
    }

    /// @brief Cleanup io_service to dismiss already putted tasks
    void close(){
        std::thread t([&]{ service().stop(); });
        t.join();
    }
protected:

// send-response methods are pretty standard

private:

    std::string _host;
    std::string _port;
    std::array<uint8_t, max_length> _reply;
    ba::io_service::work _work;
    ba_ip::udp::socket _sock;
};
```

Usage example:

```
{
    AsyncUDPClient ipc(addr, port);
    ipc.send(&archive_data[0], archive_data.size());
    // it seems client is destroyed before some internal processing is finished?
}
```

Behaviour is not deterministic, sometimes works fine, sometimes crashes, sometimes freeze.
Stacktrace shows the crash point somewhere in boost.asio internals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destruction of `AsyncUDPClient` does not properly synchronize with the thread(s) running the `io_service`.  This can result in undefined behavior being invoked when a thread processing the `io_service` attempts to interact with the `AsyncUDPClient` and its `io_service` after their lifetime has ended.

To resolve this, do not detach from the threads processing the `io_service`, and explicitly join the thread(s) once the `io_service` has been stopped.

```cpp
class AsyncUDPClient
 : public IOServiceBase
{
public:

  // ...

  void run()
  {
    _threads.emplace_back([&]{ service().run(); })
  }

  // ...

  ~AsyncUDPClient()
  {
    close();
  }

  void close()
  {
    // Stop the io_service.  This changes its state and return immediately.
    service().stop();

    // Explicitly synchronize with threads running the io_service.
    for (auto& thread: _threads)
    {
      thread.join();
    }
  }

private:

  // ...
  std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
};
```

As hinted in the comments above, [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) does not block.  It changes the state of `io_service` to stopped, returns immediately, and causes all invocations of `run()` and `run_one()` to return as soon as possible.  Calls to [`io_service::stopped()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stopped.html) immediately return the state of the `io_service`.  Neither of these calls indicate if there are threads curretly within the invocation of  `run()` or `run_one()`.